# Client not playing from streaming data in iOS

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, audiotoolbox, gcdasyncsocket

Using Below code server start recording and start streaming to connected client and its working good.

**AudioServer.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GCDAsyncSocket.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface AudioServer : NSObject<GCDAsyncSocketDelegate>
   @property (nonatomic, strong)GCDAsyncSocket * serverSocket;
   @property (nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *connectedClients;
   @property (nonatomic) AudioComponentInstance audioUnit;

  -(void) start;
  -(void) stop;
  `enter code here`-(void) writeDataToClients:(NSData*)data;
@end
```

**AudioServer.m**

```
#import "AudioServer.h"
#define kOutputBus 0
#define kInputBus 1

static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon,
                              AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                              const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                              UInt32 inBusNumber,
                              UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                              AudioBufferList *ioData) {

// TODO: Use inRefCon to access our interface object to do stuff
// Then, use inNumberFrames to figure out how much data is available, and make
// that much space available in buffers in an AudioBufferList.

AudioServer *server = (__bridge AudioServer*)inRefCon;

AudioBufferList bufferList;

SInt16 samples[inNumberFrames]; // A large enough size to not have to worry about buffer overrun
memset (&samples, 0, sizeof (samples));

bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = samples;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames*sizeof(SInt16);

// Then:
// Obtain recorded samples

OSStatus status;

status = AudioUnitRender(server.audioUnit,
                         ioActionFlags,
                         inTimeStamp,
                         inBusNumber,
                         inNumberFrames,
                         &bufferList);

NSData *dataToSend = [NSData dataWithBytes:bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData length:bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize];


[server writeDataToClients:dataToSend];

return noErr;
}


@implementation AudioServer

-(id) init
{
  return [super init];
}

-(void) start
{


[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
// Create a new instance of AURemoteIO

AudioComponentDescription desc;
desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
desc.componentFlags = 0;
desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;

AudioComponent comp = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);
AudioComponentInstanceNew(comp, &_audioUnit);

//  Enable input and output on AURemoteIO
//  Input is enabled on the input scope of the input element
//  Output is enabled on the output scope of the output element

UInt32 one = 1;
AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 1, &one, sizeof(one));

AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &one, sizeof(one));

// Explicitly set the input and output client formats
// sample rate = 44100, num channels = 1, format = 32 bit floating point

AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat = [self getAudioDescription];
AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &audioFormat, sizeof(audioFormat));
AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &audioFormat, sizeof(audioFormat));

// Set the MaximumFramesPerSlice property. This property is used to describe to an audio unit the maximum number
// of samples it will be asked to produce on any single given call to AudioUnitRender
UInt32 maxFramesPerSlice = 4096;
AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &maxFramesPerSlice, sizeof(UInt32));

// Get the property value back from AURemoteIO. We are going to use this value to allocate buffers accordingly
UInt32 propSize = sizeof(UInt32);
AudioUnitGetProperty(_audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &maxFramesPerSlice, &propSize);


AURenderCallbackStruct renderCallback;
renderCallback.inputProc = recordingCallback;
renderCallback.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);

AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &renderCallback, sizeof(renderCallback));


// Initialize the AURemoteIO instance
AudioUnitInitialize(_audioUnit);

AudioOutputUnitStart(_audioUnit);

_connectedClients = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_serverSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[self startAcceptingConnections];
 }

- (AudioStreamBasicDescription)getAudioDescription {
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioDescription = {0};
audioDescription.mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioDescription.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian;
audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame  = 1;
audioDescription.mBytesPerPacket    = sizeof(SInt16)*audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
audioDescription.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
audioDescription.mBytesPerFrame     = sizeof(SInt16)*audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
audioDescription.mBitsPerChannel    = 8 * sizeof(SInt16);
audioDescription.mSampleRate        = 44100.0;
return audioDescription;
}

-(void) startAcceptingConnections
{
NSError *error = nil;
if(_serverSocket)
    //[_serverSocket acceptOnPort:<#(uint16_t)#> error:<#(NSError *__autoreleasing *)#>]
    [_serverSocket acceptOnPort:2030 error:&error];
//TODO:- Change Here Port numbers
}


-(void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err
{
if(_connectedClients)
    [_connectedClients removeObject:sock];
}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket didAcceptNewSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)newSocket {

NSLog(@"Accepted New Socket from %@:%hu", [newSocket connectedHost], [newSocket connectedPort]);

@synchronized(_connectedClients)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(_connectedClients)
            [_connectedClients addObject:newSocket];
    });
}

NSError *error = nil;
if(_serverSocket)
    //[_serverSocket acceptOnPort:[SM_Utils serverPort] error:&error];
    [_serverSocket acceptOnPort:2030 error:&error];
//TODO:- Change Here Port numbers
}

-(void) writeDataToClients:(NSData *)data
{
if(_connectedClients)
{
    for (GCDAsyncSocket *socket in _connectedClients) {
        if([socket isConnected])
        {
            [socket writeData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
        }
        else{
            if([_connectedClients containsObject:socket])
                [_connectedClients removeObject:socket];
        }
    }
}
}

-(void) stop
{
if(_serverSocket)
{
    _serverSocket = nil;
}
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
AudioOutputUnitStop(_audioUnit);
}

-(void) dealloc
{
if(_serverSocket)
{
    _serverSocket = nil;
}
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
AudioOutputUnitStop(_audioUnit);
}


@end
```

Here is Client side code :

**AudioClient.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GCDAsyncSocket.h"
#import  <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

#import "TPCircularBuffer.h"

@protocol AudioClientDelegate <NSObject>

    -(void) connected;
    -(void) animateSoundIndicator:(float) rms;

@end


@interface AudioClient : NSObject<GCDAsyncSocketDelegate>
{
    NSString *ipAddress;
    BOOL stopped;
}

    @property (nonatomic) TPCircularBuffer circularBuffer;
    @property (nonatomic) AudioComponentInstance audioUnit;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) GCDAsyncSocket *socket;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) id<AudioClientDelegate> delegate;

    -(id) initWithDelegate:(id)delegate;
    -(void) start:(NSString *)ip;
    -(void) stop;
    -(TPCircularBuffer *) outputShouldUseCircularBuffer;


@end
```

**AudioClient.m**

```
#define kOutputBus 0
#define kInputBus 1
#import "AudioClient.h"

@implementation AudioClient

static OSStatus OutputRenderCallback(void                        *inRefCon,
                                 AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags,
                                 const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,
                                 UInt32                      inBusNumber,
                                 UInt32                      inNumberFrames,
                                 AudioBufferList             *ioData){


AudioClient *output = (__bridge AudioClient*)inRefCon;


TPCircularBuffer *circularBuffer = [output outputShouldUseCircularBuffer];
if( !circularBuffer ){
    AudioUnitSampleType *left  = (AudioUnitSampleType*)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
    for(int i = 0; i < inNumberFrames; i++ ){
        left[  i ] = 0.0f;
    }
    return noErr;
};

int32_t bytesToCopy = ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize;
SInt16* outputBuffer = ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;

int32_t availableBytes;
SInt16 *sourceBuffer = TPCircularBufferTail(circularBuffer, &availableBytes);

int32_t amount = MIN(bytesToCopy,availableBytes);
memcpy(outputBuffer, sourceBuffer, amount);

TPCircularBufferConsume(circularBuffer,amount);

NSLog(@"Bufferiiii");

return noErr;
}


-(id) initWithDelegate:(id)delegate
{
    if(!self)
    {
        self = [super init];
    }

    [self circularBuffer:&_circularBuffer withSize:24576*5];
    _delegate = delegate;
    stopped = NO;
    return self;
}

-(void) start:(NSString *)ip
{
_socket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue()];

NSError *err;

ipAddress = ip;

[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;

//if(![_socket connectToHost:ipAddress onPort:[SM_Utils serverPort] error:&err])
if(![_socket connectToHost:ipAddress onPort:2030 error:&err])
{

}

[self setupAudioUnit];
}

-(void) setupAudioUnit
{
AudioComponentDescription desc;
desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
desc.componentFlags = 0;
desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;

AudioComponent comp = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

OSStatus status;

status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(comp, &_audioUnit);

if(status != noErr)
{
    NSLog(@"Error creating AudioUnit instance");
}

//  Enable input and output on AURemoteIO
//  Input is enabled on the input scope of the input element
//  Output is enabled on the output scope of the output element

UInt32 one = 1;

status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, kOutputBus, &one, sizeof(one));


if(status != noErr)
{
    NSLog(@"Error enableling AudioUnit output bus");
}

// Explicitly set the input and output client formats
// sample rate = 44100, num channels = 1, format = 16 bit int point

AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat = [self getAudioDescription];

status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, kOutputBus, &audioFormat, sizeof(audioFormat));

if(status != noErr)
{
    NSLog(@"Error setting audio format");
}

AURenderCallbackStruct renderCallback;
renderCallback.inputProc = OutputRenderCallback;
renderCallback.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);

status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Input, kOutputBus, &renderCallback, sizeof(renderCallback));

if(status != noErr)
{
    NSLog(@"Error setting rendering callback");
}

// Initialize the AURemoteIO instance
status = AudioUnitInitialize(_audioUnit);

if(status != noErr)
{
    NSLog(@"Error initializing audio unit");
}
}

- (AudioStreamBasicDescription)getAudioDescription {


AudioStreamBasicDescription audioDescription = {0};
audioDescription.mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioDescription.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian;
audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame  = 1;
audioDescription.mBytesPerPacket    = sizeof(SInt16)*audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
audioDescription.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
audioDescription.mBytesPerFrame     = sizeof(SInt16)*audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
audioDescription.mBitsPerChannel    = 8 * sizeof(SInt16);
audioDescription.mSampleRate        = 44100.0;
return audioDescription;


}

-(void) socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err
{
if(!stopped)
    //if(![_socket connectToHost:ipAddress onPort:[SM_Utils serverPort] error:&err])
    if(![_socket connectToHost:ipAddress onPort:2030 error:&err])
    {

    }
}

-(void) socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{
if(data.length > 0)
{
    unsigned long len = [data length];

    SInt16* byteData = (SInt16*)malloc(len);
    memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);

    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {
        sum += byteData[i] * byteData[i];
    }

    double average = sum / len;
    double rms = sqrt(average);

    [_delegate animateSoundIndicator:rms];

    Byte* soundData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
    memcpy(soundData, [data bytes], len);

    if(soundData)
    {
        AudioBufferList *theDataBuffer = (AudioBufferList*) malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList) *1);
        theDataBuffer->mNumberBuffers = 1;
        theDataBuffer->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = (UInt32)len;
        theDataBuffer->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
        theDataBuffer->mBuffers[0].mData = (SInt16*)soundData;

        [self appendDataToCircularBuffer:&_circularBuffer fromAudioBufferList:theDataBuffer];
    }
}

[socket readDataToLength:18432 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}

-(void)circularBuffer:(TPCircularBuffer *)circularBuffer withSize:(int)size {
TPCircularBufferInit(circularBuffer,size);
}

-(void)appendDataToCircularBuffer:(TPCircularBuffer*)circularBuffer
          fromAudioBufferList:(AudioBufferList*)audioBufferList {
TPCircularBufferProduceBytes(circularBuffer,
                             audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mData,
                             audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);
}

-(void)freeCircularBuffer:(TPCircularBuffer *)circularBuffer {
TPCircularBufferClear(circularBuffer);
TPCircularBufferCleanup(circularBuffer);
}

-(void) socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(uint16_t)port
{
OSStatus status = AudioOutputUnitStart(_audioUnit);

if(status != noErr)
{
    NSLog(@"Error starting audio unit");
}

[socket readDataToLength:18432 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];

[_delegate connected];
}

-(TPCircularBuffer *) outputShouldUseCircularBuffer
{
return &_circularBuffer;
}

-(void) stop
{

OSStatus status = AudioOutputUnitStop(_audioUnit);

if(status != noErr)
{
    NSLog(@"Error stopping audio unit");
}

[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;

TPCircularBufferClear(&_circularBuffer);
_audioUnit = nil;
stopped = YES;
}

-(void) dealloc {
OSStatus status = AudioOutputUnitStop(_audioUnit);

if(status != noErr)
{
    NSLog(@"Error stopping audio unit");
}

[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;

TPCircularBufferClear(&_circularBuffer);
_audioUnit = nil;
stopped = YES;
}


@end
```

I want to stream Apple music library song like above, so use this code :

**Output.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@class Output;

@protocol OutputDataSource <NSObject>

- (void)readFrames:(UInt32)frames
   audioBufferList:(AudioBufferList *)audioBufferList
    bufferSize:(UInt32 *)bufferSize songData:(NSData *)songData;

@end

@interface Output : NSObject

    @property (strong, nonatomic) id outputDataSource;

    - (void)startOutputUnit;
    - (void)stopOutputUnit;
@end
```

**Output.m**

```
#import "Output.h"
#import "Utilities.m"
#import "AudioServer.h"

static OSStatus OutputRenderCallback (void *inRefCon,
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags    * ioActionFlags,
                                  const AudioTimeStamp * inTimeStamp,
                                  UInt32 inOutputBusNumber,
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                  AudioBufferList * ioData)
{

AudioBufferList bufferList;

SInt16 samples[inNumberFrames]; // A large enough size to not have to worry about buffer overrun
memset (&samples, 0, sizeof (samples));

bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = samples;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames*sizeof(SInt16);

NSData *dataToSend = [NSData dataWithBytes:bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData length:bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize];

Output *self = (__bridge Output*)inRefCon;

if (self.outputDataSource)
{


    if ([self.outputDataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(readFrames:audioBufferList:bufferSize:songData:)])
    {
        @autoreleasepool
        {
            UInt32 bufferSize;
            //[self.outputDataSource readFrames:inNumberFrames audioBufferList:ioData bufferSize:&bufferSize];
            [self.outputDataSource readFrames:inNumberFrames audioBufferList:ioData bufferSize:&bufferSize songData:dataToSend];
        }
    }                       
}

return noErr;
}

@interface Output()
    @property (nonatomic) AudioUnit audioUnit;
@end

@implementation Output

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (!self) {
    return nil;
}

[self createAudioUnit];
return self;
}

#pragma mark - Audio Unit Setup
- (void)createAudioUnit
{
// create a component description
AudioComponentDescription desc;
desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
desc.componentFlags = 0;
desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
// use the description to find the component we're looking for
AudioComponent defaultOutput = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);
// create an instance of the component and have our _audioUnit property point to it
CheckError(AudioComponentInstanceNew(defaultOutput, &_audioUnit),
           "AudioComponentInstanceNew Failed");
// describe the output audio format... here we're using LPCM 32 bit floating point samples
AudioStreamBasicDescription outputFormat;
outputFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
outputFormat.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagIsBigEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat;
outputFormat.mSampleRate        = 44100;
outputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame  = 2;
outputFormat.mBitsPerChannel    = 32;
outputFormat.mBytesPerPacket    = (outputFormat.mBitsPerChannel / 8) * outputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
outputFormat.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
outputFormat.mBytesPerFrame     = outputFormat.mBytesPerPacket;
// set the audio format on the input scope (kAudioUnitScope_Input) of the output bus (0) of the output unit - got that?
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &outputFormat, sizeof(outputFormat)),
           "AudioUnitSetProperty StreamFormat Failed");
// set up a render callback struct consisting of our output render callback (above) and a reference to self (so we can access our outputDataSource reference from within the callback)
AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
callbackStruct.inputProc = OutputRenderCallback;
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*)self;
// add the callback struct to the output unit (again, that's to the input scope of the output bus)
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(_audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &callbackStruct, sizeof(callbackStruct)),
           "AudioUnitSetProperty SetRenderCallback Failed");
// initialize the unit
CheckError(AudioUnitInitialize(_audioUnit),
           "AudioUnitInitializeFailed");
}

#pragma mark - Start/Stop
- (void)startOutputUnit
{
    CheckError(AudioOutputUnitStart(_audioUnit), "Audio Output Unit         Failed To Start");
}

- (void)stopOutputUnit
{
    CheckError(AudioOutputUnitStop(_audioUnit), "Audio Output Unit Failed To Stop");
}

@end
```

The problem is client receiving songs data but not playing, i don't know what i'm doing wrong.
Please correct me, i'm stuck here.